# Traversing a multidimensional structure and applying strip() to all strings

Tags: python, strings

I'm trying to apply `string.strip()` to all the leafs that are strings in a multidimensional collection, but my Python is a bit rusty (to say the least). The following is the best I've come up with, but I suspect there's a much better way to do it.

```
def strip_spaces( item ):
    if hasattr( item, "__iter__" ):
        if isinstance( item, list ):
            return [strip_spaces( value ) for value in item]
        elif isinstance( item, dict ):
            return dict([(value,strip_spaces(value)) for value in item])
        elif isinstance( item, tuple ):
            return tuple([ strip_spaces( value ) for value in item ])
    elif isinstance( item, str ) or isinstance( item, unicode ):
        item = item.strip()
    return item
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you are checking for an `__iter__` attribute, as you don't seem to use it. However I would recommend a couple of changes:

- Use Abstract Base Classes in the `collections` module to test duck types, such as "Iterable"
- Use `types.StringTypes` to detect string types

.

```
import collections
import types

def strip_spaces( item ):
    if isinstance( item, types.StringTypes ):
        return item.strip()

    if isinstance( item, collections.Iterable ):
        if isinstance( item, list ):
            return [ strip_spaces( value ) for value in item ]

        elif isinstance( item, dict ):
            return dict([ ((strip_spaces(key), strip_spaces(value)) \
                                    for key, value in item.iteritems() ])

        elif isinstance( item, tuple ):
            return tuple( [ strip_spaces( value ) for value in item ] )

    return item
```

Answer (score 5):

```
elif isinstance( item, dict ):
    return dict([(value,strip_spaces(value)) for value in item])
```

This will transform `{ '  a  ': '  b  ' }` into `{'  a  ': 'a' }`, which I suspect is not what you want. How about:

```
    return dict([(key, strip_spaces(value)) for key, value in item.items()])
```